# Can someone explain the HWE stack LTS package suffixes (e.g. -lts-utopic)?

Tags: upgrade, package-management, lts, hardware-enablement-stack

Can someone explain to me the LTS package postfixes/suffixes for some packages? I've done the HWE stack upgrades to get a newer kernel. For example, in my package manager, a number of variants for `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` are available:

- `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`
- `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-utopic`
- `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid`
- `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-wily`

Only the newest one (wily) is installed. My understanding is that `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is the base 14.04.0 HWE version, while `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-wily` would be the 14.04.4 HWE version.

But why are the older ones still available and shown as installable? Is there a way to hide them? They are clearly not installable.

```
apt-get install -s xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid : Depends: xorg-input-abi-21
                                          Depends: xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid (>= 2:1.16.99.901) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also, could there be compatibility problems if I boot an older kernel from a previous HWE with the currently installed newer core packages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The `-lts-wily` shows that it is a package from Ubuntu 14.04.4 HWE Stack.

Older ones are available because people have other HWE stacks installed and the should have compatible packages.

Another reason is to let users downgrade to another HWE stack.

Packages from another stack are installable, but it is a bit tricky. You can't install a standalone package, you need to replace all of them.

Comment: Could you also answer the last part of my question? The one about booting a kernel from a previous HWE.

Comment: You can boot with a previous HWE kernel. In most cases kernel version ans xorg version are not very much related. But this is not always the case. It is  not recommended to use newer xorg with opder kernel. But the other way it is OK.